# How to specify property path?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In a given xaml, there is a part:

```
<ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Black" Duration="0:0:3"/>
```

If I specify only `"Background"`, then it doesn't work. Why? Where can I get some info about making path?

P.S.: I seen some really crazy path, like `"(blablabla).(blablabla).(blablabla.blablabla)"` and it makes me nervous, because I can't find what does it means easily...

Comment: `Background` is of a `Brush` type and this is `ColorAnimation` which can animate `Color` that is published by `SolidColorBrush`. For rules check [`PropertyPath XAML Syntax`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742451(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @dkozl, it is still not very clear how to form the path. To example, `"Background.Color"` is working in my case. But this `SolidColorBrush` part inside brackets looks like type conversion and given description (in link) is very poor, limited and I feel it is incomplete. Do you know any better one?

Comment: Yes, `Background.Color` in case of `SolidColorBrush` will work just as well. Both cases will fail if there is no `Color` property just `Background.(SolidColorBrush.Color)` expects it to be `SolidColorBrush` where `Background.Color` will be happy with any `Color` property so if you would have another `Brush` type with `Color` property it will work as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work if you only specify `Background` because the storyboard animates a color, and this color is the `Color` property of the `Background` property.

`Background` is a brush, so it could contain any type of brush. In order to access the `Color` the brush needs to be converted to a `SolidColorBrush`.

This is basically what the expression `Background.(SolidColorBrush.Color)` does. It converts `Background` to a `SolidColorBrush` and then accesses the `Color` property from it.

In c# code you would write

```
       ((SolidColorBrush)Background).Color = someColor;
```

Comment: I didn't noticed it was a `Brush`. Thanks. The only question left is syntax. I would expect something like `"((SolidColorBrush)Background).Color"`, but in xaml it appears as `Background.(SolidColorBrush.Color)`. Do you know any reference to this? `Type conversion xaml` gives `TypeConverters` as result in google.

Comment: Found myself. It is called `type-qualified property`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

**Example1**

```
   <Button>
        <Button.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" From="Transparent" To="Red" Duration="0:0:0.1"></ColorAnimation>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Button.Triggers>
   </Button>
```

**example2**

```
   <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="Button"></Button>
        <Grid.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Button" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" From="Transparent" To="Green" Duration="0:0:0.1"></ColorAnimation>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Grid.Triggers>                
    </Grid>
```